# Is there a book I can read that would help me with dataweave?

Tags: dataweave

Looking for a book I can read that would help me understand more about how to write dataweave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brett, you may also want to go over functional programming concepts by reading on functional programming languages.

Haskell imho is one of the better such languages https://www.haskell.org/.  Another, albeit dated, functional language I really enjoy is ML https://polyml.org/.

Pick one and do a few exercises to get the hand out of functional programming—the concepts apply to DW too.

Answer (score 3):

No there is currently no book available. Currently besides mulesoft oficial post and docs best resource is https://www.jerney.io/tag/dataweave/